# Android Facebook updating UI

Tags: android, facebook

I have this application which connects to Facebook. For some reason I'm getting this error:

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

This is my code:

The activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    app = (AppVariables)getApplicationContext();
    context = getBaseContext();
    facebook = app.getFacebook();
    facebookRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    facebookConnection = new FacebookConnection(this);

    internetStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.internetStatus);

    facebookRunner.request("me", facebookConnection);
}

@Override
public void onFacebookResponse(String response) {
    internetStatus.setText(response);
}
```

This is FacebookConnection Class:

```
public class FacebookConnection implements RequestListener {

    private FacebookConnectionListener listener;

    public FacebookConnection (FacebookConnectionListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void updateFacebookListener(String response)
    {
        listener.onFacebookResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        updateFacebookListener(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And this is my listener interface:

```
public interface FacebookConnectionListener {

    public void onFacebookResponse(String response);

    }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *AsyncFacebookRunner* which make all of the API requests in an asynchronous fashion. To do that, it uses a different thread than the main one in which the activity is running.

When the async runner finishes it, it executes your *onFacebookResponse* method itself, instead of having the main thread executing it.

If your activity is just waiting for the graph request then don't use the *AsyncFacebookRunner* but the regular *Facebook*.

If not, then your activity should check if the data was returned, and if so update it in the original thread.

I've never had to do that before, so this is not from my personal experience, and I have not tested it, but from the code in that tutorial it seems like you just need to change your *onFacebookResponse* to something like this:

```
public void onFacebookResponse(String response) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            this.internetStatus.setText(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't understand.
that why i've written a listener.
when the AsyncFacebookRunner finishs, it calls my listener with the response.. why is it bad ?

Comment: The listener is just a way for you to know when the process is completed (failed, etc). But it has nothing to do with threads. Check out this tutorial: http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/ towards the end it shows how to do what you want.

Comment: yeah i found that, but how can do it if my RequestListener is in different java class file ? it says that he has no instance of my activity in the scope.